Ansible lookup variables and access values
I’m trying to achieve to lookup all variables in my Ansible configuration which end with "password" in their variables names. Then I would like to access the values of the password variables and check their character length.
I can lookup all my password variables with lookup('varnames', 'password') but then how do I loop over the result list and get their values?
I tried:
- name: Show passwords
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    msg: "{{ item }}"
  with_items: "{{ lookup('ansible.builtin.varnames', 'password') }}"

But what I am getting is the variable name itself:
ok: [host1] => (item=test_password,test_password_default,admin_password,ldap_password) => { "msg": "test_password,test_password_default,admin_password,ldap_password" }

I would like to get the variable values instead and then do an assertion of the character length.

Please show us what you've tried so far. Note that there is no variablenames lookup, but there is a varnames lookup, which can return a list -- which is perfect for passing to an ansible loop to do what you want.

Yes, I meant varnames lookup. But if I pass that list to with_items of a debug task, I cannot get the value with {{ item }}. Actually I am getting an error.

Please update your question to show us the playbook you've written so far. You might be close to a solution, but we can't tell without seeing the code.

By default the varnames lookup produces a single comma-delimited string. Add wantlist=true:
- name: Show passwords
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    msg: "{{ item }}"
  with_items: "{{ lookup('ansible.builtin.varnames', 'password', wantlist=true) }}"

Or use query instead of lookup (query always returns a list):
- name: Show passwords
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    msg: "{{ item }}"
  with_items: "{{ query('ansible.builtin.varnames', 'password')  }}"

(Both of the above solutions are documeted here).

Lastly, you can use the vars lookup to get the value of the variable:
- name: Show passwords
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    msg: "{{ item }}: {{ lookup('vars', item) }}"
  with_items: "{{ query('ansible.builtin.varnames', 'password')  }}"

Note that the vars lookup only returns "top-level variable names". If you actually want fact values, you may need to look them up via hostvars instead.

With both variants I am getting then a proper list but still only with the variable names in it:
ok: [host1] => (item= test_password) => {
    "msg": "test_password"
}
ok: [host1] => (item= test_password_default) => {
    "msg": "test_password_default"
}


Sorry, I missed that part of your question. See my update.
